# Odoo Server Error: Module loading training_food_delivery failed - No matching record found for 'model_food_order'

Tags: python, odoo-13

I am encountering an issue while trying to install the Odoo module "training_food_delivery." The installation fails with the following error:

Odoo Server Error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 624, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  ...
  Exception: Module loading training_food_delivery failed: file training_food_delivery/security          /ir.model.access.csv could not be processed:
  No matching record found for external id 'model_food_order' in field 'Object'
  Missing required value for the field 'Object' (model_id)
```

I have tried reviewing the `ir.model.access.csv` file within the `training_food_delivery` module and ensured that the `model_food_order` record is correctly defined. However, the error persists.

Could someone please guide me on how to resolve this error? What steps should I take to find and fix the issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're encountering an error while loading the training_food_delivery module in Odoo, specifically related to an access control configuration. The error message suggests that there's an issue with the ir.model.access.csv file and a missing external ID 'model_food_order'. Let's walk through the steps to resolve this issue.
In your ir.model.access.csv file, ensure that you have correctly defined the external ID 'model_food_order' along with the necessary access permissions. The format of this CSV file is as follows:

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_food_order,Access Food Order,model_food_order,,1,1,1,1
```

Here's a breakdown of the columns:

- id: A unique identifier for this access record.
- name: A human-readable name for the access rule.
- model_id:id: The external ID of the model to which this access rule
  applies. In your case, it should be 'model_food_order'.
- group_id:id: The external ID of the user group to which this access
  rule applies.
- perm_read, perm_write, perm_create, perm_unlink: Permissions for
  read, write, create, and delete operations. A value of 1 grants the
  permission

Make sure you have defined the model 'food.order' correctly in your module. Ensure that you have an models directory within your module folder, and the food.order model is defined in a Python file (e.g., food_order.py) inside this directory.

```
'data': [
    'security/ir.model.access.csv',
    # Other data files, if any
],
```

After making these changes, it's important to restart the Odoo server to apply the modifications. You can do this by stopping and then starting the Odoo service or by restarting your Odoo container if you're using Docker.
Hope this help